# initializing python class globally?

Tags: python, class, initialization

I have two files, one of the test.py is

```
import new.py

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        return
    def run(self):
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    one=Test()
    one.run()
```

and new.py

```
class New:
    def __init__(self):
        one.run()

New()
```

Now when i run python test.py I get this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import new.py
  File "/home/phanindra/Desktop/new.py", line 5, in <module>
    New()
  File "/home/phanindra/Desktop/new.py", line 3, in __init__
    one.run()
NameError: global name 'one' is not defined
```

But I want to use this instance of one in my New!!
Can I do this??

edit:

I want to access the variable in test.py in new.py to do some process and give them back to test.py. Isn't this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your `New` class to use the instance of `Test` you created, you have to pass it in as part of the constructor.

new.py

```
class New:
    def __init__(self, one):
        one.run()
```

test.py

```
import new

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        return
    def run(self):
        return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    one=Test()
    two = new.New(one);
```

Playing around with globals is a great way to break your code without realizing how you did it. It is better to explicitly pass in the reference you want to use.

Comment: but I want them in two different files!! I want to access the variable in test.py in new.py to do some process and give them back to test.py. Isn't this possible?

Comment: @pahnin: You can have them in to different file, this just happens to be the way I first wrote it. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The closest you can get is to pass the thing you need in to the constructor:

```
class New(object):
    def __init__(self, one):
        one.run()
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't ;-)

Comment: @ms4py: Yes, good point. I meant to say something to that effect. Cycles in the dependency tree are fun, but not good.

Answer (score -1):

`one` is defined inside the `if __name__=='__main__'` block.
Consequently, `one` will get defined only if `test.py` is run as a script (rather than imported).

For the module `new` to access `one` from the `test` module, you'll need to pull `one` out of the `if __name__` block:

**test.py:**

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        return
    def run(self):
        return 1

one=Test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    one.run()
```

Then access `one` by the qualified name `test.one`:

**new.py:**

```
import test

class New:
    def __init__(self):
        test.one.run()

New()
```

Comment: but its not the ssame instance as the intial one(), I mean if I did some math on a variable in inital one that will not be accessable from the new importin new.py

Comment: Sharing a state on module level is not a good idea. @unholysampler posted the "right" solution by passing a reference.

Comment: @pahnin: It *is* the same `one`. Try it and see.